# Qt: too many setText calls cause lag

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a central display widget, it contains many small cell widgets where each of them have some QLabels to display some text info.

I have about 100 QLabels in total. And each of them is updated in around 2 Hz.
Then my GUI thread becomes very lag...

What is the possible solutions out there?

The 100 QLabels are in a scroll area btw.

Comment: First of all refresh only visible QLabels. Are those QLabels binded to a data class? Try read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091229/how-to-data-bind-a-label-text-to-an-underlying-objects-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use a scroll area, I guess, you don't show all 100 labels at a time, right? Than you have to update only those labels that are visible. For that reason I would suggest using Qt Model-View-Controller (MVC) classes, such as QTableView, etc. That will ensure that only visible items (cells) will be processed, and performance wise this approach will be much efficient.

Comment: By using MVC, is it still to use my custom Widget? And do you think instead of setText of QLabel, rewrite its paint event and do things there will help?

Comment: @Nyaruko, what do you want to show: text, images, both?

Comment: text only any better idea?

Comment: @Nyaruko, for text only you don't need labels at all. Just create a `QTableView`, simple model for it and let each table cell contain the text you used for labels. For simpler solution you can use `QTableWidget`. In that case you will not need a model.

Comment: If I use QTableWidget, does it mean I still have to call setText for the QTableWigetItem to display the newest data?

Comment: Yes, however in case of QTableView, it will ask for the text itself through the model.

Comment: Yes, you can try to use that model.